# Carga lenta yajra/laravel-datatables

Tags: php, laravel

Summary of problem or feature request

Bueno tengo un problema la usar DataTable en laravel, por lo que vi el problema es por que tengo una relacion y al llamar los valores de la relacion esta es la que tienen un delay excesivo

Tengo 1300 registros

Tengo un delay de carga de los datos de 3-5 seg.

Cuando dejo de usar ajax para cargar los datos y sar el metodo normal (sin Server-inside), este es mucho veloz aun con la relacion de la tabla.

Alguna idea para que pueda optimizar el codigo?
De ante mano gracias

Code snippet of problem

Controller

```
public function list_user(){
$users = User::all();
$users->each(function ($users)
{
    $users->role;
});
return datatables()->collection($users)->toJson();
}
```

Js

```
function activar_tabla_users() {
$('#DataTableUser').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "searchDelay" : 500,
    "responsive": {
        orthogonal: 'responsive'
    },
    "language": {
        "url": '{!! asset('/plugins/datatables.net/latino.json') !!}'
    } ,
    "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25, 50, 75 ],
    "ajax":'{!! url('admin/list_user') !!}',
    columns: [
        {data: 'id' },
        {data: 'username'},
        {data: 'name',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return row.name + ' ' + row.lastname;
            } 
        },
        {data: 'email'},
        {data: 'role.name',
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
            var html = ''
            if ( row.role.name == 'Administrador' )
            {
                html = '<span class="label label-danger" > <label style="width:80px;"> '+row.role.name+' </label></span>';

            }else {
                html = '<span class="label label-primary" > <label style="width:80px;"> '+row.role.name+' </label></span>';
            }
            return html;
            }
        }
        }],

});
}
activar_tabla_users();
```

Comment: Tiene paginacion
Probe usando :        
 $users = User::with('role')->get();
aun asi el tiempo que tarda al pasar a la siguiente lista
oh actualizar la pagina tarda,
entre 2-4 seg

Comment: Intenta usar datatables directamente sin ese paquete. Acá un excelente tutorial de como hacerlo (aunque hay que ajustar unos detalles): https://shareurcodes.com/blog/laravel%20datatables%20server%20side%20processing. Si requires mi ejemplo con gusto te lo paso.

Comment: aun en el ejemplo usa serverside ... pero te agradeceria 
luisito201313@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que las datatables sean dinámicas siempre deben ser server-side+ajax (hasta donde sé) para que no haya necesidad de andar recargando la página, de lo contrario basta con que uses la paginación que trae por defecto laravel y te ahorras trabajo. Respecto al problema que tienes de velocidad depende de varios factores:

- Tu equipo,
- Tus datos,
- La forma como programas,
- La forma como haces tus consultas,
- La cantidad de archivos que debe leer php del framework y tu código,
- Otros...

Bueno, te anexo mi ejemplo. Solo copia y pega.

**SQL:**

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for periodos_pagos
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `periodos_pagos`;
CREATE TABLE `periodos_pagos` (
  `id_periodo_pago` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `desc_periodo_pago` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion_periodo_pago` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_modificacion_periodo_pago` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_eliminacion_periodo_pago` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_periodo_pago`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of periodos_pagos
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `periodos_pagos` VALUES ('1', '2000', '2018-06-30 00:59:47', '2018-06-30 03:36:30', null);
INSERT INTO `periodos_pagos` VALUES ('2', '2001', '2018-06-30 01:08:21', '2018-07-02 03:05:11', null);
INSERT INTO `periodos_pagos` VALUES ('3', '2003', '2018-09-21 14:59:18', '2018-09-21 15:00:02', null);
INSERT INTO `periodos_pagos` VALUES ('4', '2002', '2018-09-21 15:14:57', null, null);
INSERT INTO `periodos_pagos` VALUES ('5', '2004', '2018-09-23 20:28:01', '2018-09-23 20:28:20', null);
INSERT INTO `periodos_pagos` VALUES ('6', '2005', '2018-09-24 21:57:19', null, null);
```

**MODELO:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PeriodoPago extends Model
{ 
    protected $table = 'periodos_pagos'; 

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_periodo_pago';

    protected $fillable = ['desc_periodo_pago'];    

    protected $guarded = ['id_periodo_pago'];

    protected $dates = [
        'fecha_creacion_periodo_pago',
        'fecha_modificacion_periodo_pago',
        'fecha_eliminacion_periodo_pago'
        ];

    public $timestamps = false;  

}
```

**CONTROLADOR:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\PeriodoPago;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use DB;

class PeriodosPagosController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return View('periodos-pagos.index');
    }

    public function obtenerPeriodosPagos(Request $request)
    {
        // datatable column index  => database column name
        $columns = array(
            0 => 'id_periodo_pago', 
            1 => 'desc_periodo_pago',
            2 => 'fecha_creacion_periodo_pago',
        );

        $obtener_periodos_pago = PeriodoPago::query();

        $obtener_periodos_pago->select(
            'periodos_pagos.id_periodo_pago',
            'periodos_pagos.desc_periodo_pago',
            'periodos_pagos.fecha_creacion_periodo_pago'
        )
        ->whereNotNull(
            'id_periodo_pago'
        );


       $total_periodos_pago = PeriodoPago::whereNotNull('id_periodo_pago')
            ->count('id_periodo_pago');

        $totalData = $total_periodos_pago;


       if(empty($request->input('search.value'))){

             $totalFiltered = $totalData;

        }else{
            $search = $request->input('search.value');

            $totalFiltered = PeriodoPago::where('id_periodo_pago','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                               ->orWhere('desc_periodo_pago', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                                ->whereNotNull('id_periodo_pago')
                                ->count(DB::raw('id_periodo_pago'));

           $obtener_periodos_pago->where('id_periodo_pago','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('desc_periodo_pago', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%");

        }

       if (empty($request->input('length'))) {
            $limit = 10;
        }else{
            $limit = $request->input('length');         
        }

        if (empty($request->input('start'))) {
            $start = 0;
        }else{
            $start = $request->input('start');
        }

        if (empty($request->input('order.0.column'))) {
            $order = 'id_periodo_pago';
        }else{
            $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
        }

        if (empty($request->input('order.0.dir'))) {
            $dir = 'asc';
        }else{
            $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');
        }        

        $obtener_periodos_pago->offset($start);
        $obtener_periodos_pago->limit($limit);
        $obtener_periodos_pago->orderBy($order, $dir);

        $periodos_pago = $obtener_periodos_pago->get();

        $data = array();

        if(!empty($periodos_pago))
        {
            foreach ($periodos_pago as $periodo_pago)
            {
                $nestedData['id_periodo_pago'] = $periodo_pago->id_periodo_pago;
                $nestedData['desc_periodo_pago'] = $periodo_pago->desc_periodo_pago;                
                $nestedData['fecha_creacion_periodo_pago'] = date('j M Y h:i a', strtotime($periodo_pago->fecha_creacion_periodo_pago));

                $data[] = $nestedData;
            }
        }

        $json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval($request->input('draw')),  
            "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered), 
            "data"            => $data
        );

        return response()->json($json_data);

    }
}
```

**VISTA:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Periodos de pago</h2>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true">Listado de periodos</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="listado_periodos_pago">
                        <thead>
                            <th>No.</th>
                            <th>Periodo (año)</th>
                            <th>Fecha de registro</th>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//generar tabla al cargar pagina
var table = $('#listado_periodos_pago').DataTable({
    'language': {
        'sProcessing': 'Procesando...',
        'sLengthMenu': 'Mostrar _MENU_ registros',
        'sZeroRecords': 'No se encontraron resultados',
        'sEmptyTable': 'Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla',
        'sInfo': 'Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_',
        'sInfoEmpty': 'Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros',
        'sInfoFiltered': '(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)',
        'sInfoPostFix': '',
        'sSearch': 'Buscar:',
        'sUrl': '',
        'sInfoThousands': ',',
        'sLoadingRecords': 'Cargando...',
        'oPaginate': {
            'sFirst': 'Primero',
            'sLast': 'Último',
            'sNext': 'Siguiente',
            'sPrevious': 'Anterior'
        },
        'oAria': {
            'sSortAscending': ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente',
            'sSortDescending': ': Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente'
        }
    },
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
        'url': '{{ route("periodos-pagos.obtenerPeriodosPagos") }}',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'type': 'get'
    },
    'columns': [
        {'data': 'id_periodo_pago'},        
        {'data': 'desc_periodo_pago'},
        {'data': 'fecha_creacion_periodo_pago'}
    ],
    'rowId': 'id_periodo_pago',
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            'targets': 0,
            'className': 'text-center'
        }
    ]
});
```

**RUTAS:**

```
Route::get('periodos-de-pagos', [
    'as' => 'periodos-pagos.index',
    'uses' => 'PeriodosPagosController@index'
    ]);

Route::get('periodos-de-pagos/obtener-periodos-pagos', [
    'as' => 'periodos-pagos.obtenerPeriodosPagos',
    'uses' => 'PeriodosPagosController@obtenerPeriodosPagos'
    ]);
```

Posiblemente debas importar los estilos de datatables (css y js) en tu vista e ignorar los que trae el paquete que instalaste.